# How to give mutable access to only some members of a struct through a pointer

Tags: c++

It seems that C++ does not allow:

```
tuple<string, int> a;
tuple<const string, int>* p = reinterpret_cast<tuple<const string, int>*>(&a);
```

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Type_aliasing
The last example, pretty much forbids the case I'm interested in.

Is there any cast, or other approach that I can do to make this work that does not invoke UB? 
I want to be able to construct a pointer through which only one tuple member can be modified.

............

The excerpt below outlines what provoked the question above. I tried to make it as focused as possible but I still had to make it quite long to produce something that will compile.

```
#include <memory>
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

using namespace std;

class sorted_array{
public:
    using Entry = tuple<const string, int>;
    //using Entry = tuple<const string, int>; //inconvenient for initialization

private:
    unique_ptr<Entry[]> data_;
    size_t size_;

public:
    sorted_array(const initializer_list<Entry>& entries) :
        data_{make_unique<Entry[]>(entries.size())}, size_{entries.size()}{
            copy(entries.begin(), entries.end(), data_.get());
            sort(data_.get(), data_.get() + size_,
                [](const Entry& e1, const Entry& e2){
                    return get<0>(e1) < get<0>(e2);
            });
            //reject duplicate string keys
            //code to do so not relevant to question
    }

    //not relevant to question
    sorted_array(const sorted_array& other) = delete;

    //do binary search on sorted data and return reference to associated int
    //implementation not relevant to question but represents primary use of class
    int& operator[](const string& key);
    const int& operator[](const string& key) const;

    //These methods provoked the original question
    //Since the underlying data_ is contiguously stored in an array
    //iterators can be easily implemented using pointers
    //However it shouldn't be possible to modify the string member of Entry. Entry* allows this.
    Entry* begin(){
        return data_.get();
    }

    Entry* end(){
        return data_.get() + size_;
    }

};

int main(){

    sorted_array a{
        {"goldfish", 10},
        {"cichlid", 15},
        {"piranha", 5}
    };

    //always fine to modify int value in Entry when sorted_array not const
    for(auto& e: a){
        get<1>(e) += 2;
        cout<<get<0>(e)<<": "<<get<1>(e)<<'\n';
    }

    //don't want the string to be modifiable even when sorted_array not const
    for(auto& e: a){
        get<0>(e) += "_oops"; //legal...oops
        get<1>(e) += 1;
        cout<<get<0>(e)<<": "<<get<1>(e)<<'\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If I could just reinterpret_cast to `tuple<const string, int>*` in begin() and end() and return those pointers, as I alluded to initially, things would be perfect. It would not be possible to change the string through those pointers. However from my research, access to `tuple<string, int>` through `tuple<const string, int>*` pointers would violate the "strict aliasing" rule. Actually declaring Entry as `tuple<const string, int>` creates its own problems. This was the background I was trying to establish in previous iterations of the question.

The string key should not be modifiable because then the sorted condition could be invalidated by clients. Pointer to Entry (Entry*) is tantalizingly close to being a suitable iterator except that the string can be modified through it. So hopefully it's clear why I was asking about casting to `tuple<const string, int>*` when Entry is, in fact, `tuple<string, int>`.

So another way of phrasing the question would be: Is there a way to use pointers as the iterator while preventing modification of the string member of the tuple through the pointer (while allowing modification of the int member) when the underlying data is an array of `tuple<string, int>` not array of `tuple<const string, int>`?

At this point I am satisfied that the answer is "No, unless I'm OK with undefined behavior". A custom pointer-like iterator class will have to be written to give the kind of access to the entries that is desired.

Comment: Can you show at least some relevant parts of the code you already have please.

Comment: A lot of code isn't necessary and may only obfuscate. Basically, if I have an array of struct A{string x; int y;}; as a private member of a class and I want to return pointers to elements of the array which do not allow member x do be modified, how do I do it?  I want clients to think the underlying array is struct A{CONST string x; int y;}

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add additional information as requested.

Comment: This is not clear. Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please do not post invalid code as description, it doesn't mean anything. Please paraphrase or quote from other text that is needed to understand your question; connect what it says to things you say in your question; make your post self-contained. When exactly does a person "think the underlying array is struct"? Give a [mre] please. A "basically" or "essentially" or "in other words" that doesn't introduce or summarize a clear, precise & full description that you also give just means "unclearly".

Comment: A struct is a special case of a class where all fields are not public.

Comment: I went ahead and made an elucidating (IMO) edit. I pray it is acceptable to the powers and that I have not inadvertently "broadened" the question once more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few approaches you could take.

1. If you're up for managing the elements yourself you can reserve memory for the array (statically using [`std::aligned_storage`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage) or dynamically using your preferred allocator) and instead of assignment you construct the elements using [placement new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) and when done destroy them by explicitly calling the destructor.
2. Instead of using `std::tuple` you could use two arrays, one for keys and one for values. Then the view is a pair of pointers.
3. You could return a special view type that only allows mutable access to the value:

```
class map_element_view
{
public:
    const std::string& key() const
    {
        return std::get<0>(*m_element);
    }

    int& value() const
    {
        return std::get<1>(*m_element);
    }

private:
    std::tuple<std::string, int>* m_element;
};
```

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping to avoid creating a special type of iterator access (I wished to take advantage of the ability of pointers to function as such). However a solution such as your suggestion 3) may be unavoidable.